# Using PyBind11 with a virtual environment created at runtime

Tags: python, c++, virtualenv, pybind11, python-embedding

My goal is to embed the python interpreter using PyBind11, but to use the interpreter from a virtual env, such that installing dependencies using pip does not clutter the system paths.

There is not much information online around this topic. [Embedding python with pybind11. Virtual environment doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904149/embedding-python-with-pybind11-virtual-environment-doesnt-work) hardcodes the venv at compile time. This is insufficient, since the venv does not exist at that time, but will be created when the scripting engine is enabled at runtime.

The plan for now is to `pip install --target` into a cache dir and add it to the `sys.path`. Using the system interpreter. This is "okayish" but not using the system interpreter would be peferable.

Comment: i don't see how you could avoid to use an external interpreter in your case? You want to install dependencies, so you need a python installation for that, so unless you want to create a separate executable that just run `pip` using the embedded pybind11 interpreter (which seems like pretty overkill), I don't see the issue with your "cache" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a virtual environment to ship isolated dependencies with your software, or to use them locally, you simply need what you already have: an isolated `lib` folder.

`pybind11` does not have its own interpreter (AFAIK), it embeds the one from the Python build you're using when compiling, so you should already have a matching version of the Python interpreter you're embedding (this is the executable you pass to `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` if you're using CMake).

The only things that you should change is to not use `sys.path` but rather `site.addsitedir`, since `sys.path` will not handle everything (e.g., `.pth` files), while `site.addsitedir` will, so simply:

```cpp
py::module_::import("site").attr("addsitedir")(/* whatever */);
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to pybind11, but my understanding is that the final embed is meant to be shipped with the python library of your choice, presuming it meets the requirements of pybind11. Is this not correct?

Comment: @JSON Yes, you need to ship the Python library with your executable (e.g., the Python DLL on Windows), plus all the standard libraries you are using.