# Embedding python witn pybind11 using virtualenv

Tags: python, c++, cmake, virtualenv, pybind11

I want to use a python virtual environment with pybind11. My system uses python2 by default. I have a virtual environment (created using virtualenvwrapper) that uses python3. How should I modify the CMake to use the virtual environment?
The path of the virutalenv site-packages is

```
 ~.virtualenvs/name-of-virtual-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I tried

- [Embedding python with pybind11. Virtual environment doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904149/embedding-python-with-pybind11-virtual-environment-doesnt-work)
- [Embedding pybind11 with virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480120/embedding-pybind11-with-virtual-environment)

but that did not work for me. I am using ubuntu.

This is what I have.

CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(example)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)

add_executable(example src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE pybind11::embed)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h> // everything needed for embedding
namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace py::literals;


int main() {
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start the interpreter and keep it alive

    py::module_ sys = py::module_::import("sys");
    py::print(sys.attr("path"));
    py::print("python version: ", sys.attr("version_info"));

    }
```

output

```
python version:  sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The initial problem is that the CMake FindPython script prefers the system Python over a virtual environment by default. You can adjust this by setting [the `Python_VIRTUALENV` to `FIRST`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html#hints) (starting with CMake 3.15).

```
set(Python_VIRTUALENV FIRST)
```

Another point to keep in mind is that the `find_package` call will [select the newest version of Python unless you specify an `EXACT` version](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19820).